# How to use Sass, TypeScript and BrowserSync in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, sass, browser-sync, node-sass

Currently, every time I launch Visual Studio Code, I run:

- [Live Sass Compiler plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) by pressing a *Watch Sass* button on the VS Code status bar
- TypeScript compiler: `Terminal > Run Task ... > Show All Tasks ...> tsc: watch - tsconfig.json`
- [BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io/): I open a new terminal window in VS Code and execute: `browser-sync . -w`

[image]

Is there any way to simplify these 3 steps and reduce them to one step? Maybe I should add something to the `tasks.json` file? Instead of using *Live Sass Compiler* I can use *node-sass*, because I have run it before. However, I would like VS Code to alert me somehow in case of a Sass compile error.

Currently, the `.vscode/tasks.json` file has the following content:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "typescript",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "option": "watch",
      "problemMatcher": ["$ tsc-watch"],
      "group": "build"
    }
    {
      "type": "typescript",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "problemMatcher": ["$ tsc"],
      "group": {"kind": "build", "isDefault": true}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `browser-sync . -w` command can be run as a task:

```
{
  "type": "shell",
  "label": "Run Browsersync",
  "command": "browser-sync . -w",
  "problemMatcher": []
}
```

Additionally, both Typescript and Browsersync watcher tasks can be run automatically at Visual Studio Code startup, by adding the following option to their configuration in `tasks.json`:

```
"runOptions": {
  "runOn": "folderOpen"
}
```

You need to allow to run tasks automatically by pressing: **Ctrl + Shift + P**, and then choosing: **Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder** > **Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder**.

So with the following `tasks.json`, the TypeScript and Browsersync watchers start automatically, they don't need to be started manually anymore:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "typescript",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "option": "watch",
      "problemMatcher": ["$tsc-watch"],
      "group": "build",
      "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" }
    },
    {
      "type": "typescript",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"],
      "group": { "kind": "build", "isDefault": true }
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "Run Browsersync",
      "command": "browser-sync . -w",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" }
    }
  ]
}
```

I also configured task for node-sass watcher - it was compiling SCSS files properly, but unfortunately I didn't get any compile error notifications, if the panels at the bottom of VSC (Problems, Terminal, etc.) were minimized. The official Visual Studio Code documentation recommends using Gulp as a Sass watcher: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_automating-sassless-compilation